# Excel 2013 and Outlook opens windows, but the window doesnt draw

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a user with a randomly recurring issue with Excel 2013 and Outlook 2013 on Windows 7.

Occassionaly, this user will double click an Excel file and it opens the file, but the window doesnt draw.

Look at this image:

[image]

As you can see, the wbshp0114 file on the right is open, and the window borders are on the screen.  Also, the thumbnail preview is there, but blank.

She says if she clicks back and forth between the document that is viewable and the one that is not, it eventually draws correctly.

At first this was limited to Excel, but now she says its happened in Outlook today when clicking reply.

I saw she had Office 2007 and 2010 components installed, so I uninstalled them.  I also repaired Office.  Neither seemed to help.

There is no consistency in the error, it sometimes happens, sometimes it doesnt.

Im at a loss, any ideas?

Comment: Try turning off Office 2013's GPU acceleration perhaps?

Comment: @techie007 Looked that up.  found this article:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2761977.  will try updating the graphics drives and if that fails, turn off hardware accelleration

Comment: OK, I updated to graphics driver and thinks looked good for a while, but it happened again.  I just disabled graphics acceleration.  Lets see if that works...

Comment: Judging by your desktop shot's tray, it looks like you have Dameware installed -- I'd wonder about the compatibility of the "Mirror" video Driver that it may have installed as well.

Comment: the helpdesk staff does use dameware.  I dont use it, nor normally do helpdesk tasks, so I dont know if this is common issue or not.  I guess I can ask them...